# issue in checkbox with custom table pagging using reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

whenever I try to check any checkbox from 1st page , checkbox from other pages get checked

i.e if I try to check 1st checkbox from the 1st page, 1st position checkbox from other pages also gets checked

```
handleCheckboxCheck(e) {

        const newSelected = Object.assign({}, this.state.selected);
        newSelected[e.target.value] = !this.state.selected[e.target.value]
        this.setState({
            selected: newSelected[e.target.value]
        })
        
        
    }
<td><input type="checkbox" id={id} checked={this.state.selected ? 'checked' : ''} value={value} onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckboxCheck(e)} /></td>
```

Comment: We can not help you by just looking at description so please share your code too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering lists in react, each element needs to have a unique key. Reacts needs this internally to identify the component.

This is probably the root cause of this problem, try following:

```
<td key={id}>
  <input ... > </input>
</td>
```

Assigning a key to the input could also work, but assigning the key to the td element follows the react guideline

Comment: I tried this solution but it did not work for me as when i check any checkbox from the 1st page and move to another page and when again i come back to the 1st page , the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: That sounds like you have a data persistence problem. From the code snippet you provided i cannot deduce how the state of you component is initialized. When unmounting a component you should save the current state into a global variable which stores the state, so that on the next mount of your component this state can be accessed and used as an initial value

Comment: My suggestion: if you are using function components, the useContext hook is useful for providing a global variable

Comment: Could you please elaborate this ? as we tried your solution but it did not work for us